# Add Extra displayName to createUserWithEmailAndPassword Method

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I like to add an extra filed to insert user's name into the firebase database and then retrieve it, but i don't know if there's a way to do such thing. here's my markup code

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="DisplayName" class="form-control">
        </div>       
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
          <label class="error">{{errorMessage}}</label>
          <label class="success">{{successMessage}}</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" (click)="tryRegister(registerForm.value)" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
      </form>
```

and here's my typescript code for registering user into database

```
tryRegister(value){
     this.authService.doRegister(value)
     .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.errorMessage = "";
       this.successMessage = "Your account has been created";
     }, err => {
       console.log(err);
       this.errorMessage = err.message;
       this.successMessage = "";
     });
   }

doRegister(value) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
      .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
      }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot pass extra values to the function that require only email and password.
the thing you want can only be achieved by registering user in your data base .
this case you are only authenticating your user to data base .
try this :

```
 this.auth.signUp(this.user.email, this.user.password).then(res => {
    //get data from database
    this.database.doc('tableName/' + res.user.uid).set(data).then(resp => {
})});
```

Create users at the same time when you are authenticating.